# Добавить убрать класс body

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как добавить/убрать класс для body?

```js
$(".header__burger").on("click", function() {
    $("body").addClass("body-overflow");
});
$(".header__burger").on("click", function() {
    removeClass("body-overflow");
});
```

```css
#burger {
  padding: 12px 32px;
  background: blue;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.body-overflow {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="header__burger item-mobile">
  <div id="burger" class="header__burger--icon open-menu">клик</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `$('body').toggleClass('body-overflow')` для jQuery и `document.body.classList.toggle('body-overflow')` на Vanilla.js

Answer (score 3):

```js
$(".header__burger").on("click", function() {
    $("body").toggleClass("body-overflow");
});
```

```css
#burger {
  padding: 12px 32px;
  background: blue;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.body-overflow {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="header__burger item-mobile">
  <div id="burger" class="header__burger--icon open-menu">клик</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!